# Number of walks on integer lattice with self-edge at zero

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-walks

Consider the graph with vertices $V=\mathbb Z$ and edges
$$E=\{(n,n+1):n\in\mathbb Z\}\cup\{(0,0)\},$$
that is,
the usual integer lattice with a self-edge at zero.

For some fixed parameters $a,b,n\in\mathbb N$,
I am interested in counting the number of walks from $a$ to $b$ in $n$ steps.
This is very easy in the case where there is no self edge, but unless I'm missing something obvious, this case seems eminently more complicated.

---

Note:
Given that the adjacency matrix of this graph is quite simple, I tried computing the $(0,0)$ entry of successive powers of the adjacency matrix in hopes of getting inspiration on how to compute this case. Apparently, the only match in OEIS is [this](https://oeis.org/A098615) sequence, which is given by
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor}\left({n\choose k}-{n\choose k-1}\right)F(n-2k+1),$$
where $F(\ell)$ stands for the Fibonacci number of order $\ell$. I'm not too surprised to see ${n\choose k}$ in there, especially given the similarity of the problem with counting random walks on the integer lattice without self-edge, but I am completely baffled to see the Fibonacci numbers.

---

Given the apparent simplicity of the problem, I would be surprised if this type of problem was never solved before, but I could not find any reference.

Comment: Let $a(n)$ denote the number of walks from $0$ to $0$ in $n$ steps.  Is there a simple reason why $a(2n+1)=5^n$?

Comment: @JohannCigler: Let $f(x)$ be the g.f. for A098615. One can easily verify that $\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2}=\frac{x}{1-5x^2}=x+5x^3+5^2x^5+5^3x^7+\dots$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: Yes I know this. But I want to know if there is a simple direct argument in terms of walks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of paths from $a$ to $b$: those that do not visit the origin ($0$) and those that do visit it. I start with analyzing the second kind of paths.

### Paths that visit the origin

A path that visits the origin consists of three parts:
(i) a path from $a$ to $0$ that does not visit $0$ except at the end;
(ii) looping at $0$ (either over the self-loop or longer loops of even length);
(iii) a path from $0$ to $b$ that does not visit $0$ except at the beginning.

The number of parts (i) of length $\ell$ equals the coefficient of $x^{\ell}$ in $(x\cdot C(x^2))^{|a|}$, where
$$C(x) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$$
is the generating function for Catalan numbers. Explicitly this number can be computed as $\binom{\ell}{\frac{\ell-|a|}{2}}\frac{2|a|}{|a|+\ell}$, and it is nonzero only if $a$ and $\ell$ are of the same parity.

The number of parts (iii) is computed similarly.

To compute the number of parts (ii) of length $\ell$, we notice that the number of irreducible loops at the origin (i.e., loops that that do not visit the origin except at the beginning and end) of length $m$ equals $1$ for $m=1$ and twice Catalan number $2C_{m/2-1}$ for even $m>0$ (the factor 2 stands for looping over positive or negative numbers). In other words, their g.f. is $x+2x^2C(x^2)$. Then summing over the number $k$ of irreducible loops, we get the following g.f. for the number of parts (ii):
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (x+2x^2C(x^2))^k = \frac{1}{1-x-2x^2C(x^2)}.$$
This is also the g.f. for sequence https://oeis.org/A098615

Combining all together, we get the number of paths from $a$ to $b$ that visit the origin of length $\ell$ equals the coefficient of $x^\ell$ in
$$\frac{(x\cdot C(x^2))^{|a|+|b|}}{1-x-2x^2\cdot C(x^2)}.$$

### Paths that do not visit the origin

Without loss of generality, assume that both $a$ and $b$ are positive. Let $s>0$ be the smallest integer that is visited by a path from $a$ to $b$. Then by similar arguments to those we used above (using $s$ as a new "origin"), we get that the number of such paths of length $\ell$ equals the coefficient of $x^\ell$ in
$$\frac{(x\cdot C(x^2))^{a+b-2s}}{1-x^2\cdot C(x^2)}.$$
It remains to sum up this g.f. over $s$ from $1$ to $\min\{a,b\}$.

*UPDATE*. Fedor Petrov's argument suggests that the number of such paths of length $\ell$ is $\binom{\ell}{\frac{\ell-|a-b|}{2}}-\binom{\ell}{\frac{\ell-(a+b)}{2}}$.

Comment: Paths of first type are generalized Catalan numbers: the number of them equals $0$ if $ab\leq 0$ and equals (number of all usual paths from $a$ to $b$)-(number of all usual paths from $a$ to $-b$) otherwise.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Indeed, this is a nice argument that simplifies computation.

Comment: This is a very nice argument. But I do not see how one gets $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor}\left({n\choose k}-{n\choose k-1}\right)F(n-2k+1)$ from the generating function $1/(1-x-2x^2 C(x^2))$.

Comment: @JohannCigler: First, the g.f. given in A098615. Second, directly this can be proved as follows. The sum equals the coefficient of $x^{n+1}$ in $(1-x^2)(1+x^2)^n\frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$. From here, one can get its g.f. using Lagrange inversion -- e.g., see http://mathoverflow.net/q/32188

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: Thank you. This is a nice proof.