# Short exact sequences every mathematician should know

Tags: homological-algebra, big-list, kt.k-theory-and-homology, short-exact-sequences

I'd like to have a big-list of "great" [short exact sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence) that capture some vital phenomena. I'm learning module theory, so I'd like to get a good stock of examples to think about. An elementary example I have in mind is the SES:

$$
0 \rightarrow I \cap J \rightarrow I \oplus J \rightarrow I + J \rightarrow 0
$$

from which one can recover the [rank-nullity theorem](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/the-rank-nullity-theorem/) for vector spaces and the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).
I'm wondering what other 'bang-for-buck' short exact sequences exist which satisfy one of the criteria:

- They portray some deep relationship between the objects in the sequence that is non-obvious, or
- They describe an interesting relationship that is obvious, but is of important consequence.

Comment: Should every mathematician know what a short exact sequence is?

Comment: @VilleSalo I was under the impression every mathematician _does_ know what a short exact sequence is :) I'm a computer science student though, so I wouldn't know :D

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I definitely do not think every mathematician knows what a short exact sequence is. While this topic probably appears in most first-year PhD courses, if a mathematician goes into, say PDEs, there is no real reason they would remember this topic. Just like in computer science, if someone goes into systems they might forget the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, and a theoretical computer scientist might forget the soldering they learned in computer architecture.

Comment: I once met a mathematician who had never heard of a homeomorphism. Maybe they were not a *true* Scotsman though.

Comment: @VilleSalo : I once heard the following (probably apocryphal) story about an oral exam. Professor: "Are $M_1$ and $M_2$ homeomorphic?" Student: "$M_1$ is, but $M_2$ isn't."

Comment: @DavidWhite: first year PhD courses? I learned them in a (required) first year undergrad course... (But the department I went (Leiden) is pretty strong on algebra ― other universities in the country wait until second year...)

Comment: I don't know if it's apocryphal, but it's not a realistic clueless answer (since it would mean something if homeomorphism had a slightly different meaning).

Comment: (That said, my education certainly has serious gaps in other places, so it's easy to imagine how some curricula can get you by without exposure to this concept.)

Comment: @TimothyChow See https://mathoverflow.net/a/53905/2926, especially Gerry Myerson's first comment.

Comment: @DavidWhite Case in point, I'm into PDE and while thanks to my own curiosity I know what a short exact sequence is, I never had to depend on that knowledge neither for research nor for any compulsory class and I'd guess the same holds for many people I know. That is not to say that we don't use them, in fact there is one that is used all the time, but naming a thing of which you only know a single example isn't really helpful.

Comment: I did four years maths undergraduate at Cambridge (specialising in probability in 4th). I did 1st and 2nd year algebra courses (`Groups` and `Groups, Rings and Modules`). I'm pretty sure I never encountered 'exact sequences'. Just finishing 4yrs of PhD at Cambridge (probability), and still haven't heard of them until this question! -- not that, looking them up now, they're a complicated concept.

Comment: @DavidWhite What is a "first-year PhD course"? My PhD is research, not courses... (I've attended some lecture series that I'm interested in, but not in any official sense; I just rock up to a lecture I'm interested in and learn!) I'm aware that the US system works somewhat differently to the European system, and the UK system in particular, but I'm not very clued up on exactly how. Are these PhD courses a US thing?

Comment: If I may, I'd suggest that adding [a link to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence) would tremendously clarify the question for many readers. Those readers may or may not be mathematicians, but either way, it seems like the question would be improved, unless your goal is actually to turn away anyone who is not a "true enough mathematician" to already know what a short exact sequence is.

Comment: Do split short exact sequences count?  If so, there are many direct sum decompositions that "every mathematician should know"...

Comment: @DavidZ I added a link to Wikipedia. I was under the impression that all pure math students see this idea, hence the tongue-in-cheek title. Clearly, I'm mistaken! I shall write more straightforward titles next time: "Most spectacular exact sequences" for example.

Comment: Although the answers so far probably constitute a nice list of examples for short exact sequences, I cannot refrain from noting that this list is quite far away from what the title of the question suggests...

Comment: @SamT: Yes, it also varies in the US, but it's common to have 0-2 years of classes in addition to research requirements. (I'm a physicist, but I audited a few "PhD math classes". For example, topology I/II following Hatcher, and topology III following Milnor)

Comment: A *proof by contradiction*: I have not heard of "short exact sequences", I recognize only five of the given examples from my MSc algebra two decades ago (but would have only been able to write two with luck if you'd give me a rough description of what I'm trying to capture); I'd argue I'm a mathematician as I have an Erdös number of four via three distinct coauthors (who have their "3" via three distinct others). I've just not used much number theory. Thus, the OP asks for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Perhaps someone can edit the title.  None of the answer give an example of something every mathematician should know.

Comment: (Referring to the comment by Durinx) Perhaps this  is an answer to the question "Short exact sequences every mathematician knows".

Comment: @TimothyChow:  If you replace "homemorphic" with "isomorphic" and  talk about vector spaces, I have personally seen it (in writing, no less).

Comment: @TerryLoring : I think the title is fine as long as one takes it as a figure of speech rather than a literal statement.

Comment: Am I right in saying that the majority of people with mathematics degrees do not know what a Hilbert space is?  In which case, I highly doubt that every mathematician knows what a short exact sequence is.

Comment: @HollisWilliams: I think it depends very much on whether you mean Bachelor's degree, Master's degree or PhD, in which country/institution and possibly whether one has studied pure or applied mathematics, even though the latter two terms are not well defined. Certainly, a course in functional analysis is not required fare for a Bachelor's degree everywhere in the world and it might be possible to sidestep it in some postgraduate degrees, although how sensible that is is another matter.

Comment: I first learnt about short exact sequences during my masters, but not in any depth. I'm now doing a PhD focusing mostly on homological algebra, so short exact sequences are of course a very important aspect of my work these days. Also @HollisWilliams I've never studied Hilbert spaces. I don't know if that makes me an ill-informed mathematician, but I've simply had no need for them in my own work. Mathematics is a vast subject, you can't learn it all, so you learn what you need and what interests you. Which will often mean central concepts of certain areas will pass you by.

Comment: I think it's interesting that many of the answers to the question don't seem to satisfy the requirements of the question at all, they are of the form "here's an abelian group X, here's a subgroup Y, and now 0 -> Y -> X -> X/Y -> 0 is an exact sequence". These answers should be on another thread called "important subgroups of abelian groups", not here!

Comment: I made it out of a PhD program at a US university without knowing what a short exact sequence was.

Comment: Maybe this discussion raises the following question: What are notions that everyone in their respective fields would find basic (and would expect mathematicians from other fields to know) - while in reality people from other fields have (almost) never heard of those.

Comment: We're going to do all this work compiling this list, and then BuzzFeed is just going to steal all of our content for its next clickbait compilation.

Answer (score 135):

There is one obvious sequence that underlies all vector analysis and a lot that builds up on it, no matter if its applied analysis, PDE, physics or the original foundations of algebraic topology. Yet it is rarely written out, as the people in the applied fields prefer to split it into its constituent statements and the people in pure mathematics are inclined to immediately write down some generalization instead. What I am talking about is of course the relationship between the classic differential operators on 3D vector fields:

$$0 \to \mathbb R\to C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3;\mathbb{R}) \stackrel{\operatorname{grad}}{\to} C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3;\mathbb{R}^3) \stackrel{\operatorname{curl}}{\to} C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3;\mathbb{R}^3) \stackrel{\operatorname{div}}{\to} C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3;\mathbb{R}) \to 0 $$

Comment: FWIW, isn't this clearer when written in terms of cohomology with the $d$ operator + duality? It's unclear at first glance why the objects involved are `scalar field -> vector field -> perpendicular vector field -> scalar field`. It makes a lot more sense (to me) to think in terms of forms, where we get `scalar field[0 form] -> vector field [1 form] -> 2 forms [dual to vector field] -> 3-forms [dual to scalar field]`.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat "[T]he people in pure mathematics are inclined to immediately write down some generalization instead."

Comment: @SiddharthBhat It strongly depends on who you are talking to, that's why I deliberately chose to write it this way, because we tend to almost forget about it. I love differential forms, but I had to teach this stuff to electrical engineers for a while. Telling them about differential forms only gets you confusion and the eternal question "will it be on the exam?". But writing it out this way after having done all those "div curl = 0" and "find the potential" calculations for weeks will get you a lot of appreciation for the underlying structure.

Comment: There is also the single variable version that every freshman is implicitly exposed to: $0 \to {\mathbb R} \to C^\infty({\mathbb R}; {\mathbb R}) \stackrel{\frac{d}{dx}}{\to} C^\infty({\mathbb R}; {\mathbb R}) \to 0$.  That is to say, the fundamental theorem of calculus, complete with "+C".  Incidentally the ${\mathbb R}$ is also missing on the left of your long exact sequence.

Comment: ...well, strictly speaking the full fundamental theorem of calculus also comes with an important splitting of this short exact sequence (the definite integral).  Anyway, I submit this sequence as a literal answer to the question title of a "short exact sequence every mathematician should know".

Comment: @mlk This sequence may be short and exact, but it is not a [short exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence).

Comment: @J.vanDobbendeBruyn Can you clarify why it's not short exact? $\mathbb R^3$ has trivial De-Rham cohomology, right? Hence the sequence ought to be short-exact?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat To clarify my comment, a *short exact sequence* is an exact sequence that is of the form $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$. Sequences with slightly more (or fewer) terms do not quality, even if they are still short in a colloquial sense.

Answer (score 76):

This might be very basic, but the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0
$$
is both an injective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$, and a flat resolution of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, making it a very useful exact sequence in many homological computations.

Answer (score 75):

The [exponential sheaf sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Exponential_sheaf_sequence):
$$0\to 2\pi i\,\mathbb Z \to \mathcal O_M {\buildrel\exp\over\to}\mathcal O_M^*\to 0$$
where $\mathcal O_M$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on the complex manifold $M$, $\mathcal O_M^*$ is the sheaf of non-vanishing functions and
$$\exp : \mathcal O_M \to \mathcal O_M^*$$
is induced by the usual exponential function.

Restricting to sections over any open set $U$ we get a long exact sequence including the map
$$\cdots \to H^0(\mathcal O_U^*)\to H^1(2\pi i\,\mathbb Z|_U) \to \cdots.$$
The cohomology group $H^0(\mathcal O_U^*)$ is the set of non-vanishing holomorphic functions on $U$. Roughly speaking, the cohomology group $H^1(2\pi i\,\mathbb Z|_U)$ gives us ($2π i$ times) an integer for each closed loop in U. This map essentially tells us the winding number, around zero, of each non-vanishing holomorphic function, as we go around such a loop. I say all mathematicians should know this because the winding number is so fundamental. But this short exact sequence is also the starting point for a long path through all kinds of interesting places like the Riemann-Roch theorem.

Comment: Also, the image of a line bundle $L\in H^1(M,\mathcal{O}^\times)$ in the next cohomology group corresponds to the first Chern class $c_1(L)\in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I've been a mathematician for 30 years and one of my most cited papers introduced a new exact sequence.  Yet I have no idea what is a sheaf.  So I fail to see how this is an exact sequence every mathematician should know.

Comment: @TerryLoring I'm envious. I remember learning this stuff for the first time with great fondness (30 years ago almost exactly). I can never have that feeling again, but you can!

Comment: @DanPiponi What is a good place to learn this? This seems like a beautiful way to look at winding.

Comment: I learnt it from Gunning's "Lectures on Riemann Surfaces" (1966). Confusingly the sequel to this book is also called "Lectures on Riemann Surfaces (Jacobi Varieties)". You want the one that gives this exact sequence (written as $0\to\mathbb Z\to\mathcal O\to\mathcal O^*\to 0$) at the bottom of page 26.

Comment: I just learnt of another use of this exact sequence: On the sheaf of complex functions, this can be used to show that the cokernel pre-sheaf is not sheafy. The cokernel is locally trivial, but globally not. (https://math.mit.edu/~mckernan/Teaching/07-08/Spring/18.726/model2.pdf)

Comment: I barely know what a sheaf is, but I guess this is a generalisation of a short exact sequence that literally every mathematician *does* know: the exactness of  $0\to 2\pi i \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{C}\stackrel{\exp}{\to}\mathbb{C}_*\to 1$ is essentially Euler’s identity; $\exp(\pi i)=-1$.

Comment: @HJRW Exactly right. Now generalise to holomorphic functions from some domain U to the 3 spaces you mention. Now it gets interesting. For example on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ you can compute log continuously on small subdomains but not globally because log is "multivalued". Sheaves give a nice way to talk about the fact that local logs exist (away from 0) and $H^1$ measures the extent to which you fail to be able to extend these to global functions.

Answer (score 67):

I find it hard to believe that three days have gone by and no one has explicitly mentioned
$$
0 \to \Bbb  Z \to \Bbb R  \to \Bbb S^1 \to 0
$$

Comment: We can rewrite the $\mathbb{S}^1$ term of this sequence as the Pontryagin dual $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{T})$ of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then the resulting short exact sequence is key to the Poisson summation formula. Tate gave a similar short exact sequence in his thesis:
$$0\to K\to \mathbb{A}_K\to \text{Hom}(K,\mathbb{T})\to 0,$$
where $K$ is a global field and $\mathbb{A}_K$ is its adele ring. Note that these sequences are self-dual in the sense that applying the Pontryagin duality functor yields ``the same" sequences.

Answer (score 61):

I think a short exact sequence that every teacher should know is

$$ 0 \to \mathbb R^d \to \mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb R^d) \to \mathrm{O}(\mathbb R^d) \to 0, $$

maybe for $d=2$ or $d=3$. Better still, forget about the origin and see $E=\mathbb R^d$ as an affine space.

It is a great visual helper, in the sense that many elementary properties take a concrete sense. It makes it clear that there is a copy of the group on the left hand side (the translations) in the isometry group, and that there is some other component described by the group on the right hand side, although how to perform the decomposition is not obivous (which is of course expected for working mathematicians, but a nice way to introduce it to others). Once we describe how the right hand side sits in the isometry group, it is very visual also that is not canonical, and that in fact there is a choice to be made to define such a copy, introducing what a section is and why it is interesting/important.

Comment: More generally: semidirect products for groups.

Comment: (These are split, by the way.)

Answer (score 47):

The short exact sequence

$$ 0 \to \mathrm{rad}({\mathfrak g}) \to {\mathfrak g} \to {\mathfrak g}/\mathrm{rad}({\mathfrak g}) \to 0$$

separates a Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ into its solvable radical $\mathrm{rad}({\mathfrak g})$ and its semisimple projection ${\mathfrak g}/\mathrm{rad}({\mathfrak g})$, and is absolutely fundamental in the classification theory of Lie algebras, particularly in the characteristic zero, finite dimensional setting in which [Levi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi_decomposition) is available to split the above sequence.  Given the ubiquity of Lie algebras and Lie groups in mathematics, as well as the wider philosophy of separating algebraic objects into their "solvable" and "simple" components, I would submit that this sequence should be known to any mathematician.

In a somewhat similar spirit, the short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to [G,G] \to G \to G/[G,G] \to 0$$
that separates a group $G$ into its commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ and its abelianisation $G/[G,G]$ is generally the first step towards understanding solvable groups $G$ (because if $G$ is solvable then $[G,G]$ is also solvable with the derived length decremented by one), while the analogous short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to Z(G) \to G \to G/Z(G) \to 0$$
separating a group $G$ into its centre $Z(G)$ and the quotient $G/Z(G)$ is similarly often the first step in understanding nilpotent groups (because if $G$ is nilpotent then $G/Z(G)$ is nilpotent with the nilpotency degree decremented by one).  There are of course analogues of these sequences for Lie algebras also.

In the category of topological (or algebraic) groups, one also has the short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to G^0 \to G \to G/G^0 \to 0,$$
where $G^0$ is the [identity component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_component) and $G/G^0$ is the totally disconnected projection.  In principle, this separates the study of such groups into the connected and totally disconnected cases.

Comment: One might add to this list$$0\to H_2(G)\to[F,F]/[R,F]\to G\to0$$for perfect $G=F/R$ with free $F$, and similar extensions for Lie algebras, etc.

Answer (score 46):

"Every mathematician should know" is too much to ask, but I do think the following is a great short exact sequence that captures a vital phenomenon:
$$0 \to K(H) \to B(H) \to Q(H) \to 0.$$

$K(H)$ is the compact operators on a Hilbert space $H$, $B(H)$ is the bounded operators, and $Q(H)$ is the Calkin algebra. The "vital phenomenon" is that being invertible modulo the compacts, i.e., being Fredholm, is the same as being invertible in the Calkin algebra.

It won't help you learn module theory but IMHO it deserves to be on a big list ...

Comment: I voted up, even if this is not much more than a definition (of Calkin algebra).

Comment: @DenisSerre it's a fair comment. I guess the substantive fact is that the Calkin algebra *is* a C*-algebra --- easy enough for us now that we have the GNS construction, but it wasn't easy for Calkin ...

Comment: Would have gone for the Toeplitz extension myself :)  (haven't checked to see if it's already here)

Comment: Yeah, that's another good one.

Comment: @NikWeaver but many textbooks nowadays prove that quotients of $C^*$-algebras (by closed two-sided ideals) are once again $C^*$-algebras *before* they get into the GNS construction... (For instance, see Murphy, or Takesaki, or Blackadar.) Is it really needed? Or is this considered to be part of the GNS construction?

Comment: @J.vanDobbendeBruyn I guess the modern approach is to define C*-algebras abstractly, and you're right, we don't need GNS to see that the Calkin algebra is an abstract C*-algebra. I should have said "concrete C*-algebra".

Comment: @NikWeaver ah yes, the historical distinction between $B^*$-algebras and $C^*$-algebras... Indeed, looking at Calkin's original paper, it seems that he does not attempt to prove the $B^*$-identity, and immediately aims for a faithful representation. (In fact, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra#Some_history:_B*-algebras_and_C*-algebras), the $B^*$-identity was only introduced a few years later, in 1946.)

Comment: @J.vanDobbendeBruyn yes, if I remember right he uses something like an ultraproduct construction to do this. Anyway your point is well-taken.

Answer (score 45):

I strongly doubt there is any short exact sequence that every mathematician should know, but I certainly wish that those of them who know that for a (co)chain complex $(C,d)$
$$
0\to\operatorname{Im}(d)\to\operatorname{Ker}(d)\to H(C,d)\to0
$$
is short exact, would also know that
$$
0\to H(C,d)\to\operatorname{Coker}(d)\to\operatorname{Im}(d)\to0
$$
is short exact too.

Comment: It's sad this is so far down the list, because I think it's the only short exact sequence I actually know!

Comment: The $\text{Im}(d)$ complex in the second sequence needs to be shifted by one degree, no?

Comment: @Feryll Well, $\operatorname{Im}(d)$ can be naturally graded in two ways, shifted wrt each other: the second one comes from the isomorphism $\operatorname{Im}(d)\cong C/\operatorname{Ker}(d)$

Answer (score 41):

An example of a short exact sequence satisfying your first desiderata, but one which you probably won't fully understand till you are further along in homological algebra, is the **Universal Coefficient Theorem**. The homology version says: if $R$ is a PID, $A$ is an $R$-module, and $C$ is a flat chain complex over $R$, then there is a natural short exact sequence

$$
0 \rightarrow H_n(C) \otimes_R A \rightarrow H_n(C\otimes_R A) \rightarrow Tor_1^R(H_{n-1}(C),A) \rightarrow 0
$$

Moreover, this sequence splits, and the splitting is natural in $A$ but not in $C$.

A related result is the **Künneth Theorem**: if $R$ is a PID and $X,Y$ topological spaces then there is a natural short exact sequence

$$
0 \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i+j=k} H_i(X;R) \otimes_R H_j(Y;R) \rightarrow H_k(X\times Y; R) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i+j=k-1} Tor_1^R(H_{i}(X;R),H_j(Y;R)) \rightarrow 0
$$

Furthermore, this sequence splits, but not canonically.

Comment: Of course, there is also a dual version, with Ext and product instead of Tor and direct sum. And a universal coefficient theorem in cohomology. Look them up in Hilton and Stammbach's book (Theorems 3.1, 3.3).

Answer (score 35):

Within the category of Banach spaces and bounded linear maps,

$$0\to c_0 \to \ell_\infty \to \ell_\infty / c_0 \to 0$$

is a paradigm example of a short exact sequence that does not split, contrary to any short exact sequence

$$0\to c_0 \to X \to Z \to 0,$$

where $X$ (or $Z$) is separable. Here $c_0$ is the space of sequences convergent to 0 and $\ell_\infty$ is the space of bounded sequences, both endowed with the supremum norm.

The relevant results are Sobczyk's and Phillips-Sobczyk's theorems. See also the paper *[Sobczyk's Theorems from A to B](http://matematicas.unex.es/%7Efcabello/files/printable/21.pdf)* by Félix Cabello Sánchez, Jesus M. F. Castillo, and David Yost.

Comment: The "commutative analog" of my example! Might be worth mentioning that $l_\infty/c_0$ is isomorphic to $C(\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus \mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Evaluating at a single element of $\beta {\mathbb N}/{\mathbb N}$ one obtains the short exact sequence $0 \to o({\mathbb R}) \to O({\mathbb R}) \to {\mathbb R} \to 0$, where $O({\mathbb R})$ is the ring of bounded nonstandard reals, $o({\mathbb R})$ is the ideal of infinitesimal nonstandard reals, and ${\mathbb R}$ is the standard reals.  Also can't resist mentioning the variant $0 \to o({\mathbb Q}) \to O({\mathbb Q}) \to {\mathbb R} \to 0$, which one way to construct the real numbers in nonstandard analysis. More generally one has the nonstandard hull construction in metric or Banach spaces.

Answer (score 29):

How about the short exact sequence that expresses that every group can be expressed in terms of generators and relators? For any group $G$, there is a short exact sequence (in fact many) of the form $$0\to R\to F\to G\to 0,$$ with $F$ and $R$ being free groups. This expresses $G$ as a free group of generators modulo the relations encoded in $R$.

Of course there are analogous statements in other categories, such as those of modules.

Comment: "Analogous" should be taken with a grain of salt, since $R$ might not be free in other categories (including many module categories).

Comment: Good point. I was thinking about particularly nice rings. In general projective resolutions might be much longer.

Comment: I think this was explicitly part of my first answer to this question (and, indeed, is very worth highlighting to a newcomer like the OP) https://mathoverflow.net/a/363723/11540

Answer (score 28):

For any abelian group $A$, there is a short-exact sequence $$0 \to T(A) \to A \to A/T(A) \to 0,$$
where $T(A)$ is the [torsion subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_subgroup) of $A$, and $A/T(A)$ is [torsion-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Torsion-free_and_mixed_groups).

Answer (score 27):

The *kernel-cokernel exact sequence*: in an abelian category, given $A \xrightarrow{f} B \xrightarrow{g} C$, the following sequence is exact

$$ 0 \to \ker f \to \ker gf \to \ker g \to \text{coker } f \to \text{coker }gf \to \text{coker} g \to 0$$

The maps are the obvious ones. The map $\ker g \to \text{coker } f$ is the one which factors through $B$.

I don't know if this fits, because it's not short and maybe it is too trivial, but I really think that *every mathematician should know*. For example, at a very low level, this tells the following basic facts

1. $gf$ is injective iff $f$ is injective and $\ker g \hookrightarrow{} \text{coker }f$
2. $gf$ is surjective iff $g$ is surjective and $\ker g  \twoheadrightarrow \text{coker }f$
3. $gf$ is an isomorphism iff $f$ is injective, $g$ surjective and $\ker g \xrightarrow{\cong} \text{coker } f$
4. If $f$ and $g$ are injective/surjective, so is $gf$.

I think that more cools applications are covered in [the following paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.07528.pdf) by Xiong, which I found just now.

A nice picture of this sequence from Nakaoka's website is the following

[image]

Comment: Do you remember on exactly which website you found this image?  I don't find it at https://www.sci.kagoshima-u.ac.jp/nakaoka .

Answer (score 26):

Given a finitely generated module $M$ over a commutative Noetherian ring $R$, there is a short exact sequence $$0\to M_1 \to R^n \to M\to 0$$
where you map $1$ in each $R$ to a generator of $M$ and $M_1$ (also finitely generated) is called a module of syzygy of $M$. Understanding this sequence (and it's repetitions) is a fundamental problem in commutative algebra and algebraic geometry and has generated countless beautiful results as well as been widely used a versatile tool on it's own. For instance, Hilbert's Syzygy Theorem says that if $R$ is a polynomial ring over a field, and you repeat this with $M_1$, etc, eventually you will get a free module.

Not sure there is one thing that "everyone should know", but for instance Stanley's proof of the Upper Bound Conjecture in combinatorics used a refinement of the Hilbert Theorem above.

Comment: Since the OP is just getting started, I'll add that this story is told in section 1.8 of Zimmermann's book on representation theory, where he also explains that (by definition) the $n$-th syzygy $\Omega_M^n$ fits in a short exact sequence $0\to \Omega_M^n \to P_{\Omega_M^{n-1}} \to \Omega_M^{n-1}\to 0$. This is an important reason why the stable module category in representation theory is a triangulated category. Here $P_{\Omega_M^{n-1}}$ is as in my answer, a projective module that maps onto $\Omega_M^{n-1}$

Comment: There is also a story of cosyzygies, i.e., cokernels of injective envelopes, which also fits into the framework of short exact sequences.

Answer (score 23):

I suppose many algebraic topologists would agree that the short exact sequence

$$0\longrightarrow \mathbb Z/p \longrightarrow \mathbb Z/p^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb Z/p\longrightarrow 0$$
giving rise to the Bockstein operator in (co)homology and the exact sequence
$$ 0\longrightarrow C \stackrel{\cdot p}\longrightarrow C \longrightarrow  C/pC\longrightarrow 0$$
giving rise to the Bockstein spectral sequence of the form
$$H(C/pC) \Longrightarrow H(C)/pH(C)$$ may fit the bill. They are quite simple and lead to remarkably interesting mathematics.

Comment: In addition to the Bockstein, this is the key example to see that $\mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb Z/p, \mathbb Z/p)\ne 0$, which is nice to know. I also like $0\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/n\to 0$, as a good first example of a non-split short exact sequence but also just a general insight into how abelian groups behave differently than vector spaces.

Comment: In fact every first grader has to know this short exact sequence: it is how you do addition by “carrying”.

Comment: @VivekShende Sounds a bit dramatic but OK. :)

Comment: (I think there was a nice thread here about how carrying gives a cocycle, too...)

Answer (score 21):

The Tate extension. Let $k$ be a field, and let $V$ be the space $k((t))$ be the space of Laurent series with coefficients in $k$, considered as a topological vector space. If we write $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ for the group of (topological) automorphisms of $V$, then there is a canonical central extension

$$0\rightarrow k^{\times}\rightarrow\operatorname{GL}^{\flat}(V)\rightarrow\operatorname{GL}(V)\rightarrow0.$$

For a detailed construction, see [http://www.its.caltech.edu/~justcamp/notes/sila.pdf](http://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Ejustcamp/notes/sila.pdf). A brief summary: let $L$ be the space $k[[t]]\subset V$. Then for any element $g\in\operatorname{GL}(V)$, $gL$ and $L$ are commensurable (their intersection is of finite codimension in both) and so one can associate to them a one-dimensional vector space, the relative determinant. $\operatorname{GL}^{\flat}(V)$ can be defined as pairs of an element $g$ and a trivialization of the relative determinant.

Here the deep fact is the existence of the object $\operatorname{GL}^{\flat}(V)$. This leads to a host of other central extensions that are central (haha....) to the study of e.g. affine Lie algebras and friends (and thus to conformal field theory.) In a different direction, this short exact sequence is equivalent to the existence of the local residue symbol; in fact, I think Tate's name got attached to this because of his use of the local residue symbol to give a new proof of Riemann-Roch.

Answer (score 20):

I saw $0\to \mathbb Z_p\to \mathbb Z_{p^2}\to \mathbb Z_p\to 0$ as an answer, with $p$ prime, but I will add with $p$ not prime and the particular choice $p=10$,

$$0\to \mathbb Z_{10}\to \mathbb Z_{100}\to \mathbb Z_{10}\to 0 $$
for the following reasons:

1. We all know that the group in the middle is given by $\mathbb Z_{10}\times \mathbb Z_{10}$ twisted by a 2-cocycle.
2. We know (if we don't, we should!) that the 2-cocyle is given by $f(n,m)=0$ if $n+m<10$ and $f(n,m)=1$ if $n+m\geq 10$, where $n,m\in\{0,\dots,9\}$.
3. Every child knows (or should know) (in particular, every mathematician -even a non algebraist one-) how to sum 2-digit numbers.

Since the question is what exact sequence we "should" know, I think 3. and 2. are two good reasons, even for the two different meanings of "should" know.

Comment: What is the 2-cocycle? Is that the homology group that's generated by $Ker(g)/Im(f)$?

Comment: If the Babylonians knew about exact sequences, they would certainly know $0  \rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_6 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{60} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{10}  \rightarrow 0$. So why not also  $0  \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p \rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{pq} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{q}  \rightarrow 0$ for any natural numbers $p, q$?

Answer (score 17):

I guess the quintessential example, satisfying your second desiderata, is

$$
0 \rightarrow A \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} B \rightarrow B/f(A) \rightarrow 0.
$$

For example, if $f = \mu_n: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is multiplication by $n$, this means the following is exact

$$
0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\mu_n}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0.
$$

Another example of the same general result is that, if $C$ is finitely presented, then it fits in a short exact sequence

$$
0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow P \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0
$$

where $N$ and $P$ are finitely generated, and $P$ is projective. Think of $P$ as the generators, and $N$ as the relations you quotient out by to get $C\cong P/N$.

Since you asked for a big list, I'll try to restrict myself to one example per answer.

Comment: Even though the $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ example is very basic, I often find it extremely helpful to think about (e.g. lets you understand the difference between a SES and a direct sum).

Comment: @SamHopkins Is it different from a direct sum because it does not split?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat: yes, exactly, that's the same thing.

Answer (score 15):

Despite it being frequently used implicitly in papers (a classical example being Milnor's '56 paper about exotic spheres), I have never seen the following spelled out anywhere, so this might be a good place:

Let $\xi^n : E \to B$ be a real, smooth vector bundle over a manifold $B$. There is a short exact sequence of vector bundles over $E$,

$$0 \to \xi^*(\xi) \stackrel{i}{\to} \tau(E) \stackrel{d\xi}{\to} \xi^*(\tau(B)) \to 0,$$

where $i$ sends $(e_1, e_2) \in E \times_B E$ to the tangent vector starting at $e_1$ and pointing in the direction specified by $e_2$. Here, $\tau(M)$ denotes the tangent bundle of $M$. (As always, short exact sequences of vector bundles split.)

It follows from an easy dimension count. Alternatively, one can write out the gluing of the charts, giving something like

$$0 \to \text{colim } \mathbb R^n_\text{d} \times \mathbb R^n_\text{o} \times U_i \to \text{colim } \mathbb R^n_\text{d} \times \mathbb R^n_\text{o} \times TU_i \to \text{colim } \mathbb R^n_\text{o} \times TU_i \to 0,$$

where subscript $d$ and $o$ are just labels to distinguish between the coordinate which tracks the direction and that which tracks the origin, and $\{U_i\}$ is an atlas for $\xi$. This also gives a more rigorous description of $i$.

Comment: This must be closely related to another very important short exact sequence - the Atiyah class extension$$0\to\Omega^1\otimes E\to J^1(E)\to E\to0$$

Comment: I find it particularly illuminating when talking about connections. A right splitting ($H:\xi^*(\tau(B))\to\tau(E)$ such that $d\xi\circ H=\mathrm{id}$) is a choice of horizontal lift, while a left splitting ($K:\tau(E)\to\xi^*(\xi)$ such that $K\circ i=\mathrm{id}$), sometimes known as the connector, is the projection on the vertical part (hence $K(v)=0$ if $v$ is horizontal). The introduction of connections is a direct (human) result of the fact that this sequence does not canonically split.

Answer (score 14):

This one is just too much fun to leave out.
Write the braid group on $n$ strands as $B_n$.
By following the strands of a braid $\sigma\in B_n$ we construct a permutation of $n$ items, which we write as $\eta(\sigma)$. This $\eta$ is an epimorphism whose kernel is the pure braid group $P_n$. The pure braids are the braids whose strands end up where they started:

$$
 P_n \to B_n \overset{\eta} \to S_n 
$$

Answer (score 13):

Short exact sequences form a bridge of sorts between homological algebra and representation theory. For example, [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem) is the statement that, if $G$ is a finite group and $k$ is a field whose characteristic does not divide the order of $G$, then the $k$-representations of $G$ are completely reducible. This is equivalent to the statement that every short exact sequence of $k[G]$-modules

$$
0 \rightarrow V_1 \rightarrow V_2 \rightarrow V_3 \rightarrow 0
$$

splits. This is, in turn, equivalent to the statement that $k[G]$ is a [semisimple ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module#Semisimple_rings) (there are many equivalent forms of what this means; my favorite is that every module is both injective and projective). You can then hit it with the Artin–Wedderburn theorem and write $k[G]$ as a product of matrix algebras. Strictly speaking, you don't *need* the language of short exact sequences, but many find it clarifying.

Answer (score 12):

Another fundamental (half) short exact sequence is the Jacobi--Zariski sequence. For  algebras over operads, for example, it takes the following form: for a triple $C\to B\to A$ of maps of $P$-algebras, there is a half exact sequence of functors
$$0\longrightarrow \mathrm{Der}_B(A,-) \longrightarrow \mathrm{Der}_C(A,-) \longrightarrow\mathrm{Der}_C(B,-) $$
coming from the half exact sequences in Kahler differentials
$$A\otimes_B\Omega_{B\mid C}^1\longrightarrow \Omega_{A\mid C}^1 \longrightarrow \Omega_{A\mid B}^1 \longrightarrow 0 $$
that is exact if $B\to A$ is a cofibration.

Answer (score 12):

Decided to turn into an answer my comment to [another answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/363794/41291).

The [Atiyah class](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1957-085-01/S0002-9947-1957-0086359-5/) $\alpha_E\in\operatorname{Ext}^1(E,\Omega^1\otimes E)$ of a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ is the class of the short exact sequence
$$
0\to\Omega^1\otimes E\to J^1(E)\to E\to0,
$$
where $\Omega^1$ is the cotangent bundle (corresponding to the sheaf of holomorphic 1-forms) and $J^1(E)$ is the sheaf of first order jets of sections of $E$. A good reference is "[Rozansky-Witten invariants via Atiyah classes](https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1000664527238)" by Kapranov (Compositio Math. **115** (1999) 71-113). Kapranov notes that there is a dual way to represent this class, using another remarkable short exact sequence
$$
0\to E\to{\mathcal D}^{\leqslant1}\otimes_{\mathcal O}E\to T\otimes E\to0.
$$
Here $T$ is the tangent bundle and ${\mathcal D}^{\leqslant1}$ is the sheaf of differential operators of order $\leqslant1$. (More precisely, this gives the class corresponding to $-\alpha_E$ in view of the canonical isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\Omega^1\otimes-)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(T\otimes-,-)$.)

Answer (score 11):

For a free product $A*B$ of groups $A$ and $B$, there is the exact sequence

$1 \to [A,B] \to A*B \to A \times B \to 1$

where $[A,B]$ is the subgroup generated by all elements $[a,b]=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $A \times B$ is the direct product group. The first map is the inclusion and the second one is the intuitive one. This sequence is important for combinatorial and geometric group theory.

Answer (score 10):

A starting point in anabelian geometry (a "*thème central de la géométrie algébrique anabélienne*", as Grothendieck writes in his Esquisse d'un Programme) can be considered to be the following:

Let $k$ be a field with separable closure $\overline{k}$ and $X$ a quasi-compact, quasi-separated $k$-scheme. If $\overline{x}$ is a geometric point of $X$ and the base change $X_{\overline{k}}$ is connected, then there is a short exact sequence of profinite topological groups:

$$ 1 \to \pi^{ét}_1(X_{\overline{k}}, \overline{x}) \to \pi^{ét}_1(X, \overline{x}) \to \pi^{ét}_1(Speck, \overline{x}) \simeq Gal(\overline{k}/k) \to 1$$

In fact, for $X=\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}\backslash{\{0,1,\infty\}}$, J. S Milne on p. 30 of his LEC course notes, calls $\pi^{ét}_1(X, \overline{x})$ "*arguably, the most interesting object in mathematics*" due to the deep motivic ideas and profound connections that surround it, in relation with the already mysterious absolute Galois group of the rationals.

Answer (score 9):

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $x:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function with $0$ as regular value, such that $X=\{x=0\}\subset M$ is a smooth submanifold. Then
$$
0\rightarrow x C^\infty(M)\hookrightarrow C^\infty(M) \xrightarrow{f\mapsto f\vert_X} C^\infty(X)\rightarrow 0
$$
is a short exact sequence and a right split corresponds to an extension map.

Where does this show up:

- For $M=\mathbb{R}$ this is the statement that the remainder in a Taylor series can be written as $R(x)=x^kr(x)$ for a *smooth* function $r(x)$.
- For $M=\mathbb{R}^d\times \bar {\mathbb{R}}^d$ (where $\bar{\mathbb{R}}^d$ is the radial compactification) and $x$ a boundary defining function of $\partial M=\mathbb{R}^d\times S^{d-1} = S^*\mathbb{R}^d$ (co-sphere bundle), this yields
  $$
  0\rightarrow \Psi_{\mathrm{cl}}^{m-1}(\mathbb{R}^d)\hookrightarrow \Psi_{\mathrm{cl}}^{m}(\mathbb{R}^d) \xrightarrow{\sigma_m} C^\infty(S^*\mathbb{R}^d)\rightarrow 0,
  $$
  the shorth exact symbol sequence of pseudo-differential operators. Here $\Psi^m(\mathbb{R}^d)=\mathrm{Op}(x^{-m}C^\infty(M))$ with $\mathrm{Op}$ denoting the standard quantisation of symbols $a:\mathbb{R}^d_z\times \mathbb{R}^d_\xi\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. One can take $x=\langle \xi \rangle^{-1}$ as bdf. of fibre-infinity. A right split is then a quantisation map. The symbol sequence (together with the multiplicativity of $\sigma_m$) allows to construct parametrices of elliptic operators and is thus the starting point of elliptic regularity theory.
- For $M=\bar {\mathbb{R}}^d\times \bar {\mathbb{R}}^d$, which is a manifold with corners, the constructions from the previous point yields [Melrose's](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erbm/papers/sslaes/sslaes1.pdf)  scattering (classical) scattering pseudo-differential operators.

Comment: Can you please expand a bit on how the $M=\mathbb{R}$ case corresponds to remainders in Taylor series?

Comment: On $M=\mathbb{R}$ we take $x(t)=t$, such that $X=\{0\}$. Now, if a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(0)=0$, then by exactness of the SES we can write $f(t)=t g(t)$ for another smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Inductively, if $f(t)=O(t^k)$, then $f(t) = t^k g(t)$ for a smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. This applies to the remainder in the Taylor series, where $g$ might a priori only be bounded.

Answer (score 7):

Take a bundle $E \rightarrow M$ in $Diff$ and then apply the tangent functor. We get $TE\rightarrow TM$. The kernel of this is the vertical bundle, $VE$ and this all assembles into the short exact sequence:

$0 \rightarrow VE \rightarrow TE \rightarrow TM \rightarrow 0$

A splitting of this gives an Ehresmann connection, aka a horizontal bundle $HE$ such that $TE = VE \oplus HE$

The concept then descends to connections over vector bundles and principal bundles.

All this is in Michor, Kolar & Slovaks *Natural Operations in Differential Geometry*. It's possible to introduce curvature in this generality and which describes the local integrability of the horizontal bundle. In fact, they introduce it in greater generality over just a manifold, rather than a bundle and there they have cocurvature as well as curvature where the former describes the integrability of the vertical bundle. In the example above, the cocurvature vanishes as the vertical bundle is always integrable.

Answer (score 7):

The following is both elementary and simple, and carries a useful content, so it may qualify at least as something most mathematicians may not regret to know. In the context of formal Laurent series,

$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \rightarrow  \mathbb{C}((z)) \xrightarrow{D} \mathbb{C}((z)) \;\xrightarrow{ \mathrm{Res}    }\; \mathbb{C} \rightarrow 0,$$

describes the main features of the operation of formal residue, taking a formal Laurent series $\sum_k c_kz^k$ to its coefficient $c_{-1}$. Among other results these allow to give an easy proof of the Lagrange inversion formula (check e.g. [Genealogy of the Lagrange inversion theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25491/genealogy-of-the-lagrange-inversion-theorem) and its answers for other remarks).

Answer (score 6):

This probably isn’t a short exact sequence that *everyone* needs to know, but it’s one of some significance for mathematical physics and differential geometry.

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Any smooth principal $G$-bundle $\pi : P \to B$ gives rise to a canonical short exact sequence
$$
 0 \to \mathfrak{g} \times P \to TP \to \pi^\ast TB \to 0
$$
of $G$-equivariant vector bundles on the total space $P$, where $\mathfrak{g}$ carries the adjoint representation of $G$. Here, the map $\mathfrak{g} \times P \to TP$ is induced by the map that sends $X \in \mathfrak{g}$ to the corresponding fundamental vector field $X_P$ on $P$, while the map $TP \to \pi^\ast TB$ is given by $\pi_\ast$.

As Atiyah first observed, a principal connection can be identified with a splitting of this short exact sequence. Moreover, the gauge action of global gauge transformations on principal connections is compatible with this identification: if $f : P \to P$ is a gauge transformation and $\rho : \pi^\ast TB \to TP$ is a right splitting, then $f$ acts on $\rho$ to yield the right splitting $f_\ast \circ \rho$.

From the (somewhat idiosyncratic) perspective of noncommutative geometry, this short exact sequence can be viewed as relating the $G$-equivariant differential calculus on the total space $P$ to differential calculus on the base $B$ and the differential calculus along the orbits (modelled on that of the structure group $G$); a principal connection, then, tells you how to decompose the total differential calculus into a “direct sum” of basic and orbitwise calculi. Indeed, in noncommutative geometry itself, this short exact sequence—more precisely, a noncommutative analogue of its dual—actually becomes part of the definition of (algebraic) quantum principal bundle and principal connection.

Comment: Can you suggest some references(non-physics) which define connection as splitting of the Atiyah sequence... One that I know is the Appendix A of the book "Lie groupoids and Lie algebroids in differential geometry" by K. Mackenzie..

Comment: I wish I did! It's all been scattered articles and the odd MO post (including some of yours, in fact)—thanks for the reference to Mackenzie!

Comment: Very good answer, very close to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/a/363794/129074) as well.

Comment: On obvious reference is Atiyah's 1957 paper Complex Analytic Connections in Fiber Bundles, where Atiyah writes "Definition: A connection in the principal bundle P is a splitting of the exact sequence A(P)."

Comment: That is exactly where Atiyah first observed all this.

Answer (score 6):

A mathematician specialising in $C^*$-algebra theory should probably know the following short exact sequences. These play a central role in the $K$-theory of $C^*$-algebras.

- Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra with unitisation $A'= A \oplus \mathbb{C}$. There is an obvious split short exact sequence
  $$0 \to A \to A' \to \mathbb{C}\to 0$$
  Hence, $K_i(A') \cong K_i(A)\oplus K_i(\mathbb{C})$.
- Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the Toeplitz algebra and $\mathbb{T}$ be the unit circle and $H^2$ be the Hardy space. Then we have a short exact sequence
  $$0 \to B_0(H^2) \to \mathbb{A}\to C(\mathbb{T})\to 0$$
  This can be used to give a proof of the Bott-periodicity theorem.
- As mentioned in another answer, given a Hilbert space $H$, there is the short exact sequence
  $$0 \to B_0(H)\to B(H)\to B(H)/B_0(H)\to 0$$
  which allows us to determine the $K$-theory of the Calkin algebra (via the six-terms exact sequence).
- If $\mathbb{S}=\{f\in C(\mathbb{T}): f(1)=0\}$, there is also a trivial split short exact sequence
  $$0 \to \mathbb{S}\to C(\mathbb{T})\to \mathbb{C}\to 0$$
  which allows us to determine the $K$-theory of the $n$-dimensional torus $\mathbb{T}^n$, i.e. we can determine the $K$-theory of $C(\mathbb{T}^n)$.

Comment: For Bott-periodicity reasons $0 \to C_0(\mathbb{R}^2) \to C(S^2) \to \mathbb{C} \to 0$ is also important. The generator of $K_0(C_0(\mathbb{R}^2))$ comes from the Bott projection associated to to Hopf line bundle on $S^2$. Tensoring by $C_0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ performs the "double suspension".

Comment: @Zorngo I've been once told by the late Tamaz Kandelaki that there are similar short exact sequences involving $C(S^7)$ and $C(S^8)$ that give real Bott periodicity. Cannot remember now, I think he referred to some paper by Cuntz?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know whether this is a SES that every mathematician should know but it does satisfy the first sentence of the body of your question, since one could say it captures triangulability:

$$ 0 \to \text{ker}f \to \Theta_{3}^{H} \overset{f}{\to} \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0 $$

where:

- the abelian group $\Theta_3^H$ is the cobordism group of oriented homology three spheres modulo binding an acylic PL/smooth 4-manifold.
- f is the Rokhlin homomorphism, which is 1/8th the signature of a compact, smooth spin(4) manifold that the integral homology sphere bounds.

Galewski, Stern and Matumoto showed in the 1980s that the non-splitting of this SES is equivalent to there being non-triangulable manifolds in every dimension 5 and above. Whereas, Manolescu recently showed that the SES does not in fact split.

Answer (score 4):

A useful short exact sequence of sheaves in algebraic geometry is

$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_C(K_C) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_C(K_C + P) \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 0,$

where $Q$ is the quotient (a skyscraper sheaf with support in $P$).

Considering the long exact cohomology sequence associated to this short exact sequence leads to a standard proof of the Riemann-Roch formula for algebraic curves, since $L(C,K_C)$ is the space of global sections of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_C(K_C)$ (see the textbook on Riemann surfaces by Otto Forster).

Comment: Up to a twist, this is a special case of the ideal sheaf sequence $I_Z \rightarrow O_X \rightarrow O_Z$ for a closed subvariety $Z$ in a variety $X$. That sequence and its twists are absolutely fundamental tools in projective algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 3):

An explicit example that is my favourite is below which is in Humphreys book on Linear Algebraic Groups.

For a field $k$, let $T(n,k)$ denote the group of $n\times n$ non-singular upper triangular group and $D(n,k)$ the non-singular diagonal matrices and $U(n,k)$ upper triangular matrices with 1's in the diagonal.

$1\to U(n,k)\to T(n,k)\to D(n,k)\to 1$
is actually a split-sequence. This can be generalized to any connected solvable group leading to its structure theorem as semi-direct product of maximal unipotent normal subgroup and maximal torus subgroup.

Comment: Any *split* connected solvable group!  For example, if $k$ is imperfect of characteristic $2$ and $\theta \in k^\times$ is a non-square, then the group of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b\theta & a \end{pmatrix}$ is solvable, an extension of a so called wound unipotent group by the multiplicative group, but the maximal unipotent subgroup is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Given an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, and a diagram

$$\begin{matrix}
W & \xrightarrow{f} & Y\\
\downarrow{g} & & \downarrow{h}\\
X & \xrightarrow{k} & Z\\
\end{matrix}$$

we can form an associated sequence

$$0 \to W \xrightarrow{(g,f)} X \oplus Y \xrightarrow{(k,-h)} Z \to 0$$

Then the diagram is:

0. Commutative iff the sequence is a complex,
1. Cartesian iff the sequence is a left exact complex,
2. co-Cartesian iff the sequence is right exact complex,
3. semi-Cartesian iff the sequence is a middle exact complex.

$\hphantom{0}$

Standard disclaimer: maybe not every mathematician, etc. etc., but it would behoove anyone working with commutative & homological algebra to be aware of this. It would be quite hoove indeed.

Answer (score 2):

An example that might be useful in virtually all branches of mathematics: If $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces (over the same field $\mathbb{F}$) and if $U \subseteq V$ is a subspace, then the obvious exact sequence
$$ 0 \longrightarrow U \longrightarrow V \longrightarrow V/U \longrightarrow 0 $$
turns into the non-trivial exact sequence
$$ 0 \longrightarrow U \mathbin{\otimes} W \longrightarrow V \mathbin{\otimes} W \longrightarrow (V/U) \mathbin{\otimes} W \longrightarrow 0. \tag*{$(*)$} $$
(I rarely need exact sequences in my work, but simple manipulations like this make quotients and subspaces of tensor products much easier to deal with.)

Comment: Can you please describe why $(\star)$ is a very useful exact sequence?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat hm, yeah, *very useful* is a little too strong (so I changed it). I guess my main point is that manipulations of exact sequences make life a lot easier when dealing with subspaces and/or quotients of tensor products.

Answer (score 2):

The defining short exact sequence for Milnor's $K_2(R)$ ($R$ any ring) is

$$0\rightarrow K_2(R)\rightarrow St(R)\rightarrow E(R)\rightarrow 0$$

where $St(R)$ and $E(R)$ are the Steinberg and elementary groups.  If we cheat a little on the definition of "short" this extends to

$$0\rightarrow K_2(R)\rightarrow St(R)\rightarrow GL(R)\rightarrow K_1(R)\rightarrow 0$$

Answer (score 2):

From tensor of vector spaces, I find this exact sequence useful:
$$0\rightarrow U\otimes V'+U'\otimes V\rightarrow U\otimes V \rightarrow (U/U')\otimes(V/V')\rightarrow 0.
$$

For a commutative ring R and an element $x\in R$, denote $(0:x)=\{y\in R\colon yx=0\}$, I find this really good:
$$0\rightarrow (0:x) \rightarrow R \rightarrow Rx\rightarrow 0
$$
It can be used to show that, in a local ring, we have:
$$\mathrm{pd}_R(Rx)\leqslant 1 \iff Rx \text{ is projective } \iff x \text{ is not a zero-divisor}
$$

Comment: More generally, your second exact sequence is a special case of $1 \to G_x \to G \twoheadrightarrow G\cdot x$, for a group $G$ acting on a space $X$, and $x$ a point of $X$ with stabilizer subgroup $G_x$.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence
$$0 \rightarrow \Psi^{\mu-1}(\Omega) \overset{\iota}{\rightarrow} \Psi^\mu(\Omega) \overset{\sigma_\mu}{\rightarrow}S_{h}^{\mu}(\Omega \times (\mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus 0)) \rightarrow 0$$
is exact, where $S_{h}^{\mu}(\Omega \times (\mathbb{R}^{n} \setminus 0))$  is the space of the functions $b:\Omega \times (\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus 0) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ positively homogeneous of degree $\mu$, $\iota$ is the inclusion operator and $\sigma_\mu$ is the principal symbol of a pseudodifferential operador $B=op(b)$ with $b \in S^{\mu}(\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^{N})$.